# Plot multiple 2D functions in 3D

Tags: plotting, functions

I would like to visualize the harmonics of a Fourier series in 3D, like on this picture:

[image: example]

Is it possible to do this in Mathematica? Ofc. I know how to create basic 2D plots, but I would like to combine them in 3D to visualize the time and frequency domain at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {{t, 0, Sin[t]}, 
   {t, 1, Cos[2 t]},
   {t, 3, Sin[4 t] + Cos[3 t]},
   {t, 4, Sin[6 t] + .5 Cos[3 t]}}, 
 {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: wow, thank you :)